# Navigation Controller and View not updating when navigating back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

I have a navigation based app with a right bar button from my first view which pushes a second view to the navigation controller. Upon clicking the back button (left bar button) while viewing the second view, the top bar updates its contents but the view remains on the second pushed view. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered with this problem today. My secondary view was a `UITableView` and I did some serious mistake loading the tableview data. My mistake was initializing `NSIndexPath` with `+indexPathWithIndex:` rather than `+indexPathForRow:inSection:` while accessing the table cells. It is so unrelated but plainly it causes navigatorview to malfunction. You can control your secondary view code if there is an issue like this. Other than this, I have no idea what it may be. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my second view is just a plain view.